# Nil after fetch on related entities in core data swift 4 iOS 11

Tags: ios, core-data, ios11, swift4, xcode9

This is my model with Country And Brand entities.

[image]

I'm trying to get all brands with specified country name.
Code looks like this:

```
    var brands: [Brand]!
    let brandRequest = Brand.createFetchRequest()
    brandRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "country.name == %@", countryName!)

    if let fetchedBrands = try? container?.viewContext.fetch(brandRequest) {
        if fetchedBrands!.count > 0 {
            brands = fetchedBrands!
        }
    }
```

Everything is in database. Brands and Country are related properly, but fetchedBrands is "nil".

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Why do you ignore a potential error? And why is the `container` optional and `brands` implicit unwrapped optional ?

Comment: @vadian thx for suggestion. It realize me that I'm forgot initialize container...